# rxtools not found in Groovy

Tags: ros, c++, ros-groovy, rxtools

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In order to use RosoutPanel in C++ I include rxtools/rosout_panel.h in my class and depend on rxtools in manifest.xml. In Fuerte this works fine, but in Groovy I get a compile error because it cannot find rosout_panel.h:

```
fatal error: rxtools/rosout_panel.h: No such file or directory
```

The .h-file is present on the file system (/opt/ros/groovy/share/rxtools/src/rxtools), so why is it not found?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/60698/rxtools-not-found-in-groovy/) by [Ola Ringdahl](https://answers.ros.org/users/1011/ola-ringdahl/) on ROS Answers with karma: 328 on 2013-04-15

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2013-04-15**:
I believe it's just your typo but `rosout_panel.h` not `rosoutpanel.h` ok?

**Comment by [Ola Ringdahl](https://answers.ros.org/users/1011/ola-ringdahl/) on 2013-04-15**:
Sorry about that, I am including rosout_panel.h in the code :-)

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2013-04-15**:
And I assume you're using `rosbuild` via `rosmake`? If so, can you share `CMakeLists.txt`?

**Comment by [Ola Ringdahl](https://answers.ros.org/users/1011/ola-ringdahl/) on 2013-04-15**:
I made a very simple example that works in Fuerte but not Groovy: [http://www8.cs.umu.se/~ringdahl/ros/rxtest.tar.gz](http://www8.cs.umu.se/%7Eringdahl/ros/rxtest.tar.gz)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

rxtools is deprecated and replaced by [rqt_common_plugins](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rqt_common_plugins) in groovy

---

Originally posted by [kalectro](https://answers.ros.org/users/3904/kalectro/) with karma: 1554 on 2013-04-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ola Ringdahl](https://answers.ros.org/users/1011/ola-ringdahl/) on 2013-04-15**:
But since the package (and the h-file) is still there it should still work right?

**Comment by [kalectro](https://answers.ros.org/users/3904/kalectro/) on 2013-04-17**:
does roscd rxtools work for you in groovy? It does not for me, so I can see why it does not find the file. Just having the .h file in your fuerte workspace will not help your groovy compilation

**Comment by [Ola Ringdahl](https://answers.ros.org/users/1011/ola-ringdahl/) on 2013-04-17**:
Yes I can roscd to it and the h-files are present in the Groovy workspace as well. You have to install rxtools separately in Groovy, so that may be why why you cannot roscd to it. I used apt-get to install it.

**Comment by [kalectro](https://answers.ros.org/users/3904/kalectro/) on 2013-04-17**:
The problem is that the .h files are not inside /opt/ros/groovy/include/rxtools but in /opt/ros/groovy/share/rxtools/src/rxtools. You could fix that by just copying the files into the right folder or use rqt which would be the nicer solution

**Comment by [Ola Ringdahl](https://answers.ros.org/users/1011/ola-ringdahl/) on 2013-04-17**:
They are in the share folder in Fuerte as well. Is this something that has changed in Groovy that they have to be in the include folder?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I haven't tested it on my own, but the phenomenon reported sounds strange.

Meanwhile, @kalectro is right. Functionality of `rxtools/rosout_panel.h` should be found in [rqt_console](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rqt_console) -- Since [its API](http://ros.org/doc/groovy/api/rqt_console/html/annotated.html) isn't exactly the same, you have to find the equivalent.

A problem for you if you need to stick to `C++` may be that it's written in `python`. One (boring) workaround is to have 2 pkgs, one for `python` to utilize `rqt_console`'s API and the other in `C++`.

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2013-04-15

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1